# Complex numbers - Finding theta - C programming

Tags: c, if-statement, numbers, degrees

I am a complete beginner at programming and Ive got a task to do, its pretty much just to find R and theta from a complex number, and take appropriate action using if statements depending which quadrant it is in.

*ie; when in quadrant 1&2 use calculated theta, when in quadrant 3 subtract 180degrees from calculated theta, and when in quadrant 4 add 180 degrees to calculated theta*

Im just really having trouble finding theta, when I input 1+1j I get the correct R, but incorrect theta. I am using theta = atan(b/a);

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()   
{   
float a, b, r, j, theta, thetaquadrant3, thetaquadrant4, convert ;   

j = -1;   
b = b*-1;   
thetaquadrant3 = theta - 180;   
thetaquadrant4 = theta + 180;   

printf ("Please enter intput A and B in the form of a+bj\n");

printf ("Input A:");   
scanf ("%f" , &a);   

printf ("Input B:");   
scanf ("%f" , &b);   

if ((a>=0.0) && (b >= 0.0))   
{   
//take no action as the calculated angle is in quadrant 1      
r = sqrt (pow(a, 2) + pow(b , 2));      
printf ("R=%f\n\n" , r);     

theta = atan(b/a);   
printf ("Theta=%f\n\n", theta );   
}

if ((a<=-0.0) && (b >= 0.0))   
{   
//take no action as the calculated angle is in quadrant 2   
r = sqrt (pow(a, 2) + pow(b , 2));    
printf ("R=%f\n\n" , r);    

theta = atan(b/a);    
printf ("Theta=%f\n\n", theta );    
}

if ((a<=-0.0) && (b <= -0.0))    
{
//Quadant 3   
r = sqrt (pow(a, 2) + pow(b , 2));    
printf ("R=%f\n\n" , r);    

theta = atan(b/a);    
printf ("Theta=%f\n\n", thetaquadrant3 );    

}

if ((a>=0.0) && (b <= -0.0))    
{      
//Quadrant 4    
r = sqrt (pow(a, 2) + pow(b , 2));   
printf ("R=%f\n\n" , r);    

theta = atan(b/a);    
printf ("Theta=%f\n\n", thetaquadrant4 );    
}    

// Converting back to rectangular Co-ordinates    
convert = r*cos(theta) + j*r*sin (theta);    
printf ("Corresponds to%f\n\n" , convert);     

return 0;   
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: There is a function called `atan2(dividend, divisor)` for this.

Answer (score 3):

First problem:

```
float a, b, r, j, theta, thetaquadrant3, thetaquadrant4, convert ;
```

these variables are `declared` but their value is `undefined`.

```
thetaquadrant3 = theta - 180;   
thetaquadrant4 = theta + 180;
```

`thetaquadrant3` and `thetaquadrant4` are now `undefined` values + or - 180, i.e. still `undefined`.

```
theta = atan(b/a);    
printf ("Theta=%f\n\n", thetaquadrant3 );
```

You need to recalculate `thetaquadrant3` based on `theta`.

But the main problem is that `atan` returns a result in radians and not degrees (as your +/- 180 would suggest you expect).

As dialer mentions in his comment, there is a function that can also handle quadrants, [atan2](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/atan2/). At the link you will also see how to show the results in degrees in your output.

Comment: Thanks very much! but Im kinda struggling to convert radians to degrees using atan2

Comment: @user2252867 did you look at the example in the atan2 reference?

Comment: yeah, im just not very familiar with this, so far I am using theta = atan(b/a); to find theta in radians, im just abit puzzled as to where I go next. I guess I scrap using atan(b/a) and use theta = atan2 (b,a) * 180 / PI; ?

Comment: The two problems are independent. Both `atan` and `atan2` return a result in radians. In fact, all the C trig functions either accept and/or return values expressed in radians. So when you calculate `convert` you still need `theta` to be in radians. You should use a separate variable `theta_degrees` for display purposes only. Read the documentation for the functions you use...

Comment: Got it! Not sure if this is correct use or not but I got it converted by                                                 

        theta = atan (b/a);
    degrees = theta * 180 / PI;
    printf ("Theta=%f\n\n", degrees );

Answer (score 0):

A little different from the approach you are already taking but if you are using C99 or above you can make use of the `<complex.h>` header file.

Using this file you can create a complex number and use the `cabs` and `carg` methods to compute the absolute value (R) and the argument (theta).

```
float _Complex num = real + (imag * _Complex_I);

float r = cabs(num);
float theta = carg(num);
```

I have created a full example [as a gist](https://gist.github.com/iwillspeak/5329918#file-complex-c).

Comment: Got it! Not sure if this is correct use or not but I got it converted by                                                 

        theta = atan (b/a);
    degrees = theta * 180 / PI;
    printf ("Theta=%f\n\n", degrees );

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Complex numbers can be a little tricky sometimes.